# Difficulty concatenating strings on separate lines into the same line while copying from one file into a new one

Tags: python, fasta

I want to copy strings from one file and place them into a new one. It is in fasta format so there are lines that contain headers with sequence identifiers. The succeeding lines contain the sequence until the next header. For downstream applications I need the sequence to be on one line. I am having difficulty concatenating the sequence strings into one line while still preserving the fasta format.

I wrote a script that should identify ">","A","G","C" or "T" as the start of a line and perform specific actions with it. If it starts with ">" it should paste the contents of the line. If it starts with any of the letters it should take that line and append it to the previous line. I have made it work so that it can perform everything correctly for the first sequence, however for any other sequences in the fasta file, lines starting with ">" are appended to the previous line.

```
import os
import glob

location = input("location: ")
os.chdir(location)
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(location, '*.fasta')):
        outputfile = open("test.fasta", "w")
        sequencefile = open(file, "r")
        lines = sequencefile.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith(">"):
                outputfile.write("\n"+line+"\n")
            elif line.startswith("G"):
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                outputfile.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("A"):
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                outputfile.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("C"):
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                outputfile.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("T"):
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                outputfile.write(line)

sequencefile.close()
outputfile.close()


Expected:
ORIGINAL FILE:

>somebacterianame1
AGCT
GCAT
CGAT
AGAT

>somebacterianame2
AGCA
CGAT
AGAT
CGAT

>somebacterianame3
AGAT
GTTA
CCTA
AGAT

NEW FILE:
>somebacterianame1
AGCTGCATCGATAGAT
>somebacterianame2
AGCACGATAGATCGAT
>somebacterianame3
AGATGTTACCTAAGAT

ACTUAL OUTCOME:

NEW FILE:
>somebacterianame1
AGCTGCATCGATAGAT>somebacterianame2
AGCACGATAGATCGAT>somebacterianame3
AGATGTTACCTAAGAT
```

Comment: With your input and your code, the output I get is close enough to what you expect, except for a few extra '\n'. Can you check your input/outputs?

Comment: Also, if you have multiple `.fasta` files in `location`, it looks to me that the output `test.fasta` file will be overwritten at every round, and only keep the last file processed in that location.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I removed the last "/n" and it worked. How odd, I could have swore it didn't. And yes the test.fasta was intentional, I just wanted a temporary output to overwrite. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. I made some simplifications that might help expanding if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the original code works as-is, with just an extra `\n` around. However, I think the code can be a little simplified taking advantage of some python constructs and shortcuts. Here what I would do:

```
    import os
    import glob

    location = input("location: ")
    os.chdir(location)
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(location, '*.fasta')):
            outputfile = open("test.fasta", "w")
            sequencefile = open(file, "r")
            lines = sequencefile.readlines()
            is_first_line = True
            for line in lines:
                # since you only check the first character, we can make a mode condensed check
                if line[0] == ">":
                    if is_first_line:
                        outputfile.write(line)  # here keep the trailing newline and do not prepend a newline
                        is_first_line = False   # flip the flag: not anymore the first line
                    else:
                        outputfile.write("\n" + line)  # here keep the trailing newline and prepend a newline
                elif line[0] in "GACT":
                    outputfile.write(line.strip())  # here strip the trailing newline
    sequencefile.close()
    outputfile.close()
```